# Install windows metro app through command line

Tags: visual-studio-2010, microsoft-metro, command-prompt

I can build a metro app using a batch script. Can any let me know how do I install this metro app using command line.

Answer (score 0):

From command line use DISM.

```
Dism /Online /Add-ProvisionedAppxPackage /FolderPath:C:\Test\MyMetroApp /SkipLicense
```